# Decomposition of a space as a union of two closed subspaces that dosen't form an Mayer-Vetoris pair.

Tags: algebraic-topology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

When applying Mayer-Vietoris sequence in homology theory, one case is where $X=X_1\cup X_2$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are closed subspaces of $X$ and $X_1\cap X_2$ is a deformation retract of one of its open neighborhood. I want to find examples where $X_i$ are closed subspaces of $X,X_1\cap X_2\neq \emptyset$ but don't form an Mayer-Vetoris pair. Appreciation for any comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Griffith's twin cone](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://wildtopology.com/2014/06/28/the-griffiths-twin-cone/&ved=2ahUKEwj_4vOYurn6AhXTh_0HHbYVDRMQFnoECB0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3j2tplv0t4dM2hco7onKSz).

It is a union of two closed contractible subspaces which meet in a single point. Its first homology group is infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Such an example is indeed heuristic.